# Ocultando valores do gráfico

Tags: r, ggplot2

Gostaria de deixar plotado no gráfico a seguir somente os valores referentes aos meses de JAN e FEV do eixo x.

A ideia é manter todos os meses do eixo X evidentes no gráfico e ao longo do tempo ir alimentando as variáveis com os valores futuros.

Não obtive sucesso nas pesquisas.

Segue o comando utilizado e um modelo ilustrando como desejo plotar.

```
dados <- read.table(text = 
              "Mes    local1 captura1  local2 captura2
              Jan     15      0         17      -0.002
              Fev     15      0         17      -0.02
              Mar     15   1500         17      85
              Abr     15    500         17      78
              Mai     15   1490         17      80
              Jun     15   1500         17      87
              Jul     15   1600         17      82
              Ago     15   1750         17      64
              Set     15   1800         17      86
              Out     15   1450         17      73
              Nov     15   1600         17      61
              Dez     15   1400         17      92
                ", header = T)
head(dados)
levels(dados$Mes)
dados$Mes = factor(dados$Mes, levels=c("Jan", "Fev", "Mar", "Abr", "Mai", "Jun", 
                                   "Jul", "Ago", "Set", "Out", "Nov", "Dez"))
ggplot(dados, aes(x = Mes)) +
geom_line(aes(y = captura1, color="15"), size=1, group = 1, linetype=1) +
geom_line(aes(y = captura2*14, color="17"), size=1, group = 2, linetype=4) +
geom_point(aes(y = captura1), color="purple", size=4, group = 1, shape=18) +
geom_point(aes(y = captura2*14), color="red", size=4, group = 2) +
scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./14, name = "Total de capturas 2")) +
labs(y = "Total de capturas 1", x = "Tempo (meses)") + 
scale_color_manual(name="LOCAL", values=c("#35978f", "#003c30"), 
                 guide = guide_legend(override.aes=aes(fill=group))) +
theme(legend.position=c(.8, 0.3))
```

[image: Imagem ilustrativa]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode usar `subset` para especificar o subconjunto dos dados a serem plotados e expandir os limites dos eixos com a opção `limits` das `scale_*`. Eis um exemplo simplificado:

```
ggplot(subset(dados, Mes %in% c("Jan", "Fev")), aes(Mes)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = captura1), group = 1) +
  geom_point(aes(y = captura1), group = 1) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = levels(dados$Mes)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = range(dados$captura1))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]